# redirect output for a command that takes in multiple arguments

Tags: shell, io-redirection, time, output

this command is to redirect output of `time` to with multiple args:

```
$ time wc test >wc.out 2>time.out
```

unix programming environment book shows that the error output of `time` redirects to `time.out`, but it seems that it's treating the `2>time.out` portion as part of the `wc` command and not redirecting the error output to `time.out` as I expected, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The usual solution to this problem is to put your `time` command in a group:

```
$ { time wc test >wc.out; } 2>time.out
```